# CSS - Style short list of articles but parents is smaller then childs

Tags: html, css

Hey gus i am styling short list of articles with name of it, author and few other things, in general my code work ( its not best but work) and looks like:

[image]
problem is i just noticed that my a href and p and h2 elemtns are entering to other one which is totaly bad in my eyes, how ever i try to fix it give it display block for a href but its just not work at all.

Is here anyone who can help me to make that tags equal to childs and not interfere to other elements?

HTML:

```
<div id="article-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg"  alt="Popis"></a>
            <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
            <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
                Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
            <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
            <hr>
        </li>
      
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
            <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
            <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
                Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
            <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
            <hr>
        </li>
  
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
            <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
            <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
                Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
            <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
            <hr>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#article-container{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:90%;
    height: 144px;
}

#article-container br, hr {
    display:none;
}
#article-container ul {
    width:960px;
    height: 144px
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 0;
}
#article-container li {
    width:310px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 8px;
}
#article-container li a{
    display:block;
}
#article-container img {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}
#article-container a img {
    border:2px solid #999e8a
}
#article-container a:hover img {
    border-color:#000
}
#article-container h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#article-container h2 a {
    color:#4d4d4d
}
#article-container h2 a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin:0
}
#article-container p span {
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0
}
#article-container p.more {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden
}


#article-container p.more a {
    color:#2e79bc;
    line-height: 27px;
}
#article-container p.more a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p.more a.links {
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#2e79bc;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#article-container p.more a.links:hover {
    background:#000
}
```

Demo : [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qB8V4/)  Whole [WEBSITE DEMO](http://funedit.com/andurit/new/)

Thanks for reading this POST :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
overflow: none;
```

to enter all the tag.

Comment: yea that can be true man but my main problem is that if u check <a> tag its 382px x 0px and thats a problem when image is 112px x 112px or something like that and if u check p element its like crossing other elements . Thats main problem i have to fix atm. 

Anyway thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qB8V4/5/)**

This section is kind of a mini layout with a right and left side.

What i suggest is wrap both section in a div and use display table-cell technique.

HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="article-item-left"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.funedit.com/andurit/new/images/foto.jpg"  alt="Popis"></a></div>
    <div class="article-item-right">
        <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
        <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span>
        <br>Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he?</p>
        <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a>
        <br/> <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
    </div>
    <hr/>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
 #article-container .article-item-left img{
     float: none;
 }
 .article-item-left, .article-item-right{
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:top;
 }
```

Oh and that anchor was 0 in height cuz the image inside it was floating.